# Match file tags with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, id3, audio-player

When transferring music from an iPod onto a computer the file names are in an "encrypted" form. I'm making a Visual Basic program to go through the folder of music I copy onto my desktop and rename the tracks based on the "title" from the details of the file. When I run my code for a `mp3` file, it works perfectly. However, when I run it on a `m4a` file I am thrown an error on this section of my code.

```
Dim TitleFrame As String = "TIT2"
        Dim foundFrame As String = ""
        Dim index As Integer = -1
        Do
            index += 1
            foundFrame = Chr(Data(index)) & Chr(Data(index + 1)) &      Chr(Data(index + 2)) & Chr(Data(index + 3))
        Loop Until foundFrame = TitleFrame
```

The error that is gives me is that it says the array is out of bounds, referring to the line that starts with `foundFrame = chr...`. I am assuming it is because this `m4a` file type has a different frame identifier for the title than `TIT2`.

Please help me either match the frame type or by giving me a programmatic way around not knowing the type of frame I'm looking for but still finding the title information. Preferably without downloading anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a different frame identifier, change your `Loop Until` statement to this:

```
Loop Until foundFrame = TitleFrame Or index = String(Data).Length - TitleFrame.Length
```

Alternatively, only execute your loop if the data contains the string, like this:

```
If String(Data).Contains(TitleFrame) Then
    ' Loop through
End If
```

Or, to quicken things up, you can do away with the loop, and use this, giving a `Boolean` value if the data contains `TIT2`:

```
String(Data).Contains(TitleFrame)
```

That should stop the exceptions.

### Here's a technical reason why:

Let's say I have data equalling a string of this SHA-256 hex hash to the text `Stack Overflow`:

```
185A76793EFF17B079F576328881972DABABED51764F1AB5AFED4C9ACEF64D55
```

Note how that string doesn't ever contain `TIT2`. The `If` statement should catch this right away and simply not look for `TIT2`.

However, I also want to explain my changes to the loop. You will note, again, this string doesn't contain `TIT2`. The execution would be like this:

```
index ............. foundFrame
0 ................. 185A
1 ................. 85A7
2 ................. 5A76
... skipping through ...
59 ................ 64D5
60 ................ 4D55
```

The indexes of the ending characters would be this:

```
6  4  D  5  5
59 60 61 62 63
```

We're making the length to check the same as `TitleFrame.Length`, which is `4`. When `index` is `59`, `foundFrame` should be `64D5`, indexes `59`, `60`, `61`, and `62.`

When it's `60`, it makes `foundFrame` `4D55`, indexes `60`, `61`, `62`, and `63`.

**This is where the loop should end to avoid an out-of-bounds exception.** If we tried `index` at `61`, we would get `61`, `62`, `63`, and `64`. `64` doesn't exist and the program crashes.

I could've used `String(Data).Length - 4`, but I wanted to use `TitleFrame.Length` in case you wanted to modify `TitleFrame` to be something else other than `TIT2`.